# Any working react native horizontal swiper/carousel with dynamic height and infinte loop?

Tags: react-native

I'm looking for an horizontal swiper/carousel plugin/solution for react native with dynamic content height and infinite loop. Some plugin tried:

Can't handle auto-height

- https://github.com/reactrondev/react-native-web-swiper/issues/17
- https://github.com/dohooo/react-native-reanimated-carousel/issues/88
- https://github.com/callstack/react-native-pager-view/issues/532

No infinite loop

- https://github.com/gusgard/react-native-swiper-flatlist/issues/29
- https://github.com/callstack/react-native-pager-view/issues/539

Not Maintained anymore:

- https://github.com/phil-r/react-native-looped-carousel
- https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel
- https://github.com/nick/react-native-carousel

Does anyone find a working plugin or solution to achieve this kind of component?